# Looping a function with Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have some function that takes a DataFrame and an integer as arguments:

```
func(df, int)
```

The function returns a new DataFrame, e.g.:

```
df2 = func(df,2)
```

I'd like to write a loop for integers 2-10, resulting in 9 DataFrames. If I do this manually it would look like this:

```
df2 = func(df,2) 
df3 = func(df2,3) 
df4 = func(df3,4) 
df5 = func(df4,5) 
df6 = func(df5,6) 
df7 = func(df6,7) 
df8 = func(df7,8) 
df9 = func(df8,9) 
df10 = func(df9,10)
```

**Is there a way to write a loop that does this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of thing is what lists are for.

```
data_frames = [df]
for i in range(2, 11):
    data_frames.append(func(data_frames[-1], i))
```

It's a sign of brittle code when you see variable names like `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, etc. Use lists when you have a sequence of related objects to build.

> To clarify, this data_frames is a list of DataFrames that can be concatenated with data_frames = pd.concat(data_frames, sort=False), resulting in one DataFrame that combines the original df with everything that results from the loop, correct?

Yup, that's right.  If your goal is one final data frame, you can concatenate the entire list at the end to combine the information into a single frame.

> Do you mind explaining why data_frames[-1], which takes the last item of the list, returns a DataFrame? Not clear on this.

Because as you're building the list, at all times each entry is a data frame.  `data_frames[-1]` evaluates to the last element in the list, which in this case, is the data frame you most recently `append`ed.

Comment: To clarify, this `data_frames` is a list of DataFrames that can be concatenated with `data_frames = pd.concat(data_frames, sort=False)`, resulting in one DataFrame that combines the original `df` with everything that results from the loop, correct?

Comment: Do you mind explaining why `data_frames[-1]`, which takes the last item of the list, returns a DataFrame? Not clear on this.

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin I edited answers to your comments in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `itertools.accumulate` as follows:

sample data

```
df:
    a   b   c
0  75  18  17
1  48  56   3

import itertools

def func(x, y):
    return x + y

dfs = list(itertools.accumulate([df] + list(range(2, 11)), func))

[    a   b   c
 0  75  18  17
 1  48  56   3,     a   b   c
 0  77  20  19
 1  50  58   5,     a   b   c
 0  80  23  22
 1  53  61   8,     a   b   c
 0  84  27  26
 1  57  65  12,     a   b   c
 0  89  32  31
 1  62  70  17,     a   b   c
 0  95  38  37
 1  68  76  23,      a   b   c
 0  102  45  44
 1   75  83  30,      a   b   c
 0  110  53  52
 1   83  91  38,      a    b   c
 0  119   62  61
 1   92  100  47,      a    b   c
 0  129   72  71
 1  102  110  57]
```

`dfs` is the list of result dataframes where each one is the adding of 2 - 10 to the previous result

---

If you want `concat` them all into one dataframe, Use pd.concat

```
pd.concat(dfs)

Out[29]:
     a    b   c
0   75   18  17
1   48   56   3
0   77   20  19
1   50   58   5
0   80   23  22
1   53   61   8
0   84   27  26
1   57   65  12
0   89   32  31
1   62   70  17
0   95   38  37
1   68   76  23
0  102   45  44
1   75   83  30
0  110   53  52
1   83   91  38
0  119   62  61
1   92  100  47
0  129   72  71
1  102  110  57
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` with a `format`ted string:

```
for i in range(2, 11):
    exec("df{0} = func(df{1}, {0})".format(i, i - 1 if i > 2 else ''))
```